# Not able to apply the Focus styles to styled component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to apply focus style to input of text but not able to apply the same.I referred to other questions and
Tried putting in outline: none to override the user stylesheet but that doesn't have any effect.

```
export const InputBox = styled.input`
  display: flex;
  width: 45%;
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(
    360deg,
    #b0a7e6 0%,
    rgba(176, 167, 230, 0) 169.23%
  );
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid lavender;
  color: #6e5dcc;
  & :focus {
outline:none
    border: 2px solid green;
  }
`;
```

Comment: could you reproduce your problem on codesandbox?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-brook-qiclk?file=/src/Components/TestForm/index.js

Comment: I want to be able to change border style on focus

Comment: the point is here: `& :focus`, please remove the space to `&:focus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space between `&` and `:focus`. I changed it to `&:focus` and it worked for me on the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks alot...Almost spent 2 hours :-)

Comment: No problem. Sometimes we have one of these days... :D

Comment: @sgrmhdk dont worry it happens to everyone

Answer (score 0):

Try this. it will worked:

```
export const InputBox = styled.input`
  /* This renders the input above... Edit  */
    display: flex;
  width: 45%;
  height: 2em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  background: linear-gradient(
    360deg,
    #b0a7e6 0%,
    rgba(176, 167, 230, 0) 169.23%
  );
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid lavender;
  color: #6e5dcc;
  &:focus {
outline:none
    border: 2px solid green;
  } `}
`

render(
  <div>
<input name="name" type="text"/>
    <Button target="_blank" primary>click</Button>

  </div>
)
```